# How can I parse a CSV with php but ignore the commas and double quotes in the strings

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file into an array. Unfortunately one of the columns contains commas and quotes (Example below). Any suggestions how I can avoid breaking up the column in to multiple columns?

I have tried changing the deliminator in the fgetcsv function but that didn't work so I tried using str_replace to escape all the commas but that broke the script.

Example of CSV format

```
title,->link,->description,->id
Achillea,->http://www.example.com,->another,short example "Of the product",->346346
Seeds,->http://www.example.com,->"please see description for more info, thanks",->34643
Ageratum,->http://www.example.com,->this is, a brief description, of the product.,->213421

    // Open the CSV
    if (($handle = fopen($fileUrl, "r")) !==FALSE) {

        // Set the parent array key to 0
        $key = 0;

        // While there is data available loop through unlimited times (0) using separator (,)
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {

           // Count the total keys in each row
           $c = count($data);

           //Populate the array
           for ($x = 0; $x < $c; $x++) {
           $arrCSV[$key][$x] = $data[$x];
           }
           $key++;
        } // end while

        // Close the CSV file
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Comment: Can you change the csv yourself? The easiest is to pick a separator sign that is not used, otherwise escaping is useful.  What do the "->" signs mean?

Comment: If it's a proper CSV file, then fields containing commas should be quoted, and quotes within a field should be escaped

Comment: Arend, No unfortunately I cant.

Comment: Mark Baker, thanks I will have a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should think about using PHP's [file()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)-function which reads you CSV-file into an array.

Depending on your delimiter you could use [explode()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) then to split the lines into cells.

here an example:

```
$csv_file("test_file.csv");

foreach($csv_file as $line){
  $cell = explode(",->", $line);  // ==> if ",->" is your csv-delimiter!

  $title[] = $cell[0];
  $link[] = $cell[1];
  $description = $cell[2];
  $id[] = $cell[3];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work but I decided not to use it. Instead I followed Mark Bakers suggestion above.