# Correct way to handle CSV Files on PHP

Tags: php, csv, laravel-5

Hi I have the following brain braking thing going on. The thig is that I'm developing a Laravel Application that imports and exports CSV files. Now, the data that the application Imports/Exports(I/E now on) has fields from various data types, we have text and numbers, now the text can contain commas(,) and using the default CSV separator (,) on php can lead to fields on the import to generate incorrectly. The client suggested that I I/E using ^ as a separator for the export and (,) again for the import of the data. Now, my question is, can I trust when I/E data using the default separator? Can anyone suggest a best way to do the I/E process?

**Edit**
The client main struggle is because he uses Excel on a Mac to edit the CSV files, now on my Mac, I can easily edit the files without any issues regarding the separator, of course if the separator is a comma (,) but if we use the ^ as a separator then my excel is a mess and he's ommit some fields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple google search for "php csv" would have pointed you to the documentation of phps CSV handling functions. They are capable of handling all that in a secure and convenient manner. Including escaping which obviously is required.

Comment: You don't need anything special other then `fgetcsv` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php and `fputcsv` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a CSV with php but ignore the commas and double quotes in the strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091059/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-with-php-but-ignore-the-commas-and-double-quotes-in-the-st)

Comment: I downvoted because I seriously cannot believe a search did not yield any results. Even Stackoverflow has had similar questions asked a few times below.

Comment: @crafter I think that your down vote was not necessary at all. I have searched on google and on SO for the correct answer to my question with no luck, instead of down voting can't you suggest an answer. ;)

Comment: Don't take it personally. First, I took the time to indicate why I downvoted. Second, I did provide a link for duplicate posts (of of several in fact) from here on SO (see my comments above).

Comment: @crafter Sorry, your comments were very helpful. I have checked the possible duplicate and it was fine. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't re-invent the wheel.  Re-use a well-written well-tested package.  On good one is [CSV](http://csv.thephpleague.com/) from [The PHP League](https://thephpleague.com/).

(Historical note about delimiters: the most overlooked (for 50+ years) feature in computing is that the ASCII charset (and therefore UTF8 too) assigned specific chars for delimiting fields (or units, as they called them) and records ... and even groups of records and entire files.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text.  But instead folks didnt RTM and so used commas, etc to separate fields and newlines (\r, \n, \r\n) to separate records.  D-oh!!!  So, if you are able to select your own delimiters and want to be safe by using a char not used for any other purpose, use the ASCII delimiters.)

Comment: @BareNakedCoder - wonder what Excel would think about thát :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "CSV standard". Therefore, having a "default" comma is not exactly true. One can basically use whatever one likes, and the column and line seperaters as well as the enclosures for values or complete lines really depend on what you are planning to put in as data.

TL;DR: It is totally up to you and your client, what you are using as those characters.

Comment: You are right, but your response does not provide a working solution for the original question. Rather add this as a comment to the question.